# Facebook chatlist sidebar stopped displaying in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, facebook

It just suddenly happened. Facebook sidebar with chat list  doesn't show up. Other parts of the page show up well. I'm just going mad. Shows up well in other browsers too.

Comment: what channel are you on? stable/beta/dev/canary?

Comment: @Sathya stable channel